# Grant access to Vertica SQL Tables to everyone using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vertica

I'm using a Python script to create tables and insert data into them. However, only I'm able to see the tables created. My team members can't view them. How do I change this?

What Python statements can I include to grant access to everyone? I'm using 'vertica_python' and 'sqlalchemy' to connect to database via Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for granting privileges is (see [GRANT (Table)](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/GRANT/GRANTTable.htm)):

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE <schema>.<table> TO <user>;
```

You can grant the following privileges on tables:

- `SELECT`
- `INSERT`
- `UPDATE`
- `DELETE`
- `REFERENCES`
- `TRUNCATE`

Before you grant privileges on the table, you have to at least grant `USAGE` on the table's schema.

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA <schema> to <user>;
```

If however, these tables are all in the same schema, you can grant privileges to users on the schema level. To do this, first you have to [enable schema inheritance](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/DBUsersAndPrivileges/Privileges/EnableSchemaInheritance.htm). Then grant the privileges on the schema to the users. That way you don't need to keep granting privileges on tables as you create them.

```sql
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SCHEMA <schema> TO <user>;
```

Answer (score 1):

**To grant permissions such as select privileges requires that you first have such permissions.**

According to Vertica's site, the ability to GRANT requires:

> - A superuser can grant privileges on all object types to other users.
> - An object owner can grant privileges on the object to other users using the optional WITH GRANT OPTION clause.

---

### A pseudo solution

[Depending on who needs access](https://www.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/GRANT/GRANTTable.htm), you can either use username, role, or PUBLIC (all).

Here are some example statements - as I have not worked out of vertica myself, I cannot test this

```
GRANT SELECT on all tables in schema myschema TO [user/role/PUBLIC] WITH GRANT OPTION; 
GRANT PRIVILEGE
```

OR

```
GRANT SELECT on schema.TABLENAME TO [user/role/PUBLIC] WITH GRANT OPTION; 
GRANT PRIVILEGE
```

[it may also require GRANT USAGE on schema as well](https://www.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/GRANT/GRANTSchema.htm)

---

### Processing Request with Python

And to process it through sqlalchemy in a python script (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288581/managing-user-privileges-in-sqlalchemy) for caveats):

```
sSQL = "my sql grant statement(s)"
with oSuperEngine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sSQL)
    conn.execute("COMMIT")
```